# convergence of $\sum^\infty_{k=3} \frac{(-1)^{k}3^{k+1}}{2^{2k-4}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine the convergence of the series, so I evaluated the limit such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}3^{k+1}}{2^{2k-4}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}3^{k}3}{2^{2k}2^{-4}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}3^{k}}{2^{2k}}\frac{3}{2^{-4}}$$

Clearly I can simplify the expression a little more, but after that I do not know how to determine the limit.

Any help?

Comment: Observe that $2^{2k} = 4^k$, so the first term can be expressed as $\left(-\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^k$.

Comment: Clearly, but what can I deduce from that last expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can apply the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), which states that an alternating series converges if $|a_k|$ decreases monotonically and $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} a_k = 0$.

In this case,
$$a_k = \frac{(-1)^k3^{k + 1}}{2^{2k - 4}} = \frac{(-1)^k3^k \cdot 3}{2^{2k} \cdot 2^{-4}} = \frac{(-1)^k3^k}{4^k} \cdot 3 \cdot 2^4 = 48\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^k$$

Therefore,
$$\frac{|a_{k + 1}|}{|a_k|} = \frac{48\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k + 1}}{48\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k} = \frac{3}{4} < 1$$
so $|a_k|$ monotonically decreases.

Moreover,
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k = 48\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^k = 0$$
Hence, the series
$$\sum_{k = 3}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k3^{k + 1}}{2^{2k - 4}}$$
converges by the Alternating Series Test.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the Leibniz test and the root test you can also apply the ratio test:
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| & = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{3^{n+2}}{2^{2n-2}}\times\frac{2^{2n-4}}{3^{n+1}}\right| = \frac{3}{4} < 1
\end{align*}

Hence it converges.

Hopefully this helps !